# Как соединить View с виджетом?

Tags: java, android

В программе создаю View с помощью SurfaceView. Рисую на нём всё необходимое и указываю его в качестве контента

```
setContentView(myView);
```

Layout-файл отсутствует за ненадобностью.
Мне нужно теперь вставить в myView стандартный виджет, например, Button. Чтобы на экране отображался myView со вставленной в него кнопкой. Как поступить в данной ситуации? Layout-файла нет - куда вставлять Button?

Comment: Для нескольких видов нужен `ViewGroup`. Если не хотите использовать `.xml`, то создайте программно какой-нибудь `FrameLayout` и поместите в него `SurfaceView` и свою кнопку

Comment: @Вася Воронцов, да я бы использовал .xml, но не знаю как. Подскажите, как из готового SurfaceView сделать xml?